# Select all changes in Xcode 9 Commit

Tags: xcode, git

I am using Cocoa pods for my Xcode project and there are lots of files in each of the modules, and I just ran a `pod update` and there are a TON of changes in my Source Control -> commit tab. **Is there anyway to select all the changes instead of going through them one by one as it would take forever?** I tried the classics like Shift-Click and others but they did not work.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Right click at any file and then select "Check All"

Comment: Kept trying to right-click on the checkboxes :facepalm:

Comment: This saves hours!!

Comment: Oh god, thank you so much. I've spent so much time doing it the long way.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Didn't know this.. Spent long hours

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of how to do this within Xcode, but you could open the directory in your terminal and use `git add` with wildcards to stage and commit the appropriate files.

However, if you go this route, make sure you type `git status` first and are certain that you do want to commit all of the files that are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Or use a source control system like Fork
https://git-fork.com/

Comment: Fork isn't a version control system. It's a _client_ for a version control system, namely [Git](https://git-scm.com/).